# Javascript - Image onload

Tags: javascript

I have a function in my js file to get the file height.

```
Util.isImageSize = function (file, callback) {
    var fileUpload = file;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileUpload.files[0]);
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = e.target.result;
        image.onload = function () {
            var height = this.height;
            callback(height);
        };
    }
}
```

This is where I called the function

```
Util.isImageSize(document.getElementById('fileImage'), function(height) { 
    alert(height);
});
```

I am getting am error that says

```
Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function at Image.image.onload
```

I am really stuck at this right now

Comment: try a console.log(callback) instead of executing it.  If it's undefined, then you most likely have a scoping issue.

Comment: use URL.createObjectURL instead of using the filereader

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you looking for, but I still can alert image height

```
var Util = {};

Util.isImageSize = function (file, callback) {
    console.log(file);
    var fileUpload = file;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(fileUpload.files[0]);
    reader.onload = function (e) {
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = e.target.result;
        image.onload = function () {
            var height = this.height;
            callback(height);
        };
    }
}


document.getElementById('fileImage').addEventListener('change', function() {
    Util.isImageSize(this, function(height) { 
    alert(height);
});
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/15487/

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function at Image.image.onload. i am still getting this, any idea why?

Comment: @vinz are you calling directly that `Util.isImageSize` , because see the above example he is calling onchange event.

Comment: it is inside a btn.click event. it should work the same right?

Comment: console.log(callback); before the callback shows undefined :(

Comment: @vinz: Where is `btn.click`? Could you show us more information about this?

Comment: @TanDuong     $('#btnSave').click(function() {

        document.getElementById('fileLogo').addEventListener('change', function() {
            Util.isImageSize(this, function(height) { 
                alert(height);
            });
        })

Comment: @vinz: Move `addEventListener('change'` to outside click event

Comment: cool it works! is there any way i can use it in a click event?

Comment: @vinz: You can save it with another variable and use in click event